# Multiple case expression and stuff functions in select statement cause very bad performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, stuff

I'm trying to combine multiple rows and multiple columns into one column.
I've a table like below:

Parent table:

```
ID Name
1  A
2  B
```

Child table:

```
ID Score1 Score2 Remark1 Remark2
1  0      0      Good1!   Excellent1!
1  0      0      Good1!   Great1!
2  0      1      Good2!   Excellent2!
```

Based on ID in both tables I want my output like below:

```
ID Name CountScore1+Score2 CombinedRemark
1  A     2                  Good1!,Excellent1!;Good1!,Great1!
2  B     1                  Good2!
```

Here what I've tried and it worked and for actual table there's 16 score column and remark column. Hopefully there's better clean approach in term of performance especially?

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name,
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN c.Score1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN c.Score2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [CountScore1+Score2],
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN c.Score1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Remark1 FROM Child c1 WHERE c1.ID = p.ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') ELSE '' END+';'+ CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN c.Score1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Remark2 FROM Child c1 WHERE c1.ID = p.ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') ELSE '' END [CombinedRemark]
FROM Parent p
LEFT JOIN Child c ON c.ID = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Name
```

Comment: FYI its a case expression not statement

Comment: Thanks Dale, appreciate if you have a better idea to improve my query.

Comment: Looks fine to me...

Comment: Based on your query, the CombinedRemark column result for ID 1 will be ' Good1!, Good1!; Excellent1!, Great1!'.  Is it an expected one?

Comment: Yes expected, any improvement can be made ?